# HTTP post in angular v8 and getting typescript errors

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

I'm currently getting an error message that says....where the event.id is unknown

> "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse'."

I have the interface of:

```
interface UploadPostResponse {
 id: string;
}
```

this is my POST call...config is just the POST and some params attached to it

```
return this.httpClient.request( config )
                  .subscribe(event => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                      this.router.navigate(['/inbox'], { queryParams: { inboxName: event.id } });
                    }
                  });
```

I'm not sure where to put the "UploadPostResponse" interface in so that the event.id for the inboxName will be fine..

EDIT:

```
const config = new HttpRequest('POST', `${postUrl}`,{file: inbox});
```

Comment: Can you show what `config` is

Comment: Set breakpoint on the response line this.router.navigate.  What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

The response payload is in the `body` property of the response. You should get the `id` from `event.body.id`.

```js
return this.httpClient.request( config )
  .subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      this.router.navigate(['/inbox'], { queryParams: { inboxName: event.body.id } });
    }
  });
```

You would query the returned object directly if using `httpClient.post`.

```js
return this.httpClient.post(postUrl, {file: inbox})
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/inbox'], { queryParams: { inboxName: response.id } });
  });
```